The terminal process failed to launch: Path to shell executable "c:\Users\laraq\OneDrive\Bureau\TPs_C_Jad_Laraqui\TP-INFO\TP3\gcc" does not exist
hello im a beginner in coding and when i excute my programme i get this: The terminal process failed to launch: Path to shell executable "c:\Users\laraq\OneDrive\Bureau\TPs_C_Jad_Laraqui\TP-INFO\TP3\gcc" does not exist.
can anyone help me ?
tried to watch some youtube videos but  nothing really worked for me

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
